# Enabling CORS in ear packaging

Tags: maven, ejb, cors, resteasy, ear

Consider, an ejb module (hello-ejb) which contains the stateless ejb class as follows.

```
@Stateless
@Path("/v1")
public class HelloREST{

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public String sayHello(){
        return "Hello REST";
    }
}
```

My JaxRest Activator class as follows :

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {

    private Set<Object> sigletons = new HashSet<Object>();

    private Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public JaxRsActivator() {
        classes.add(HelloREST.class);
    }

    public Set<Object> getSigletons() {
        return sigletons;
    }

    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }
}
```

Now, I added the maven dependency for cors-filter in my ejb pom.xml as follows :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml details for cors-filter in war module as follows :

```
      <filter>
        <!-- The CORS filter with parameters -->
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>

        <!-- Note: All parameters are options, if omitted the CORS 
             Filter will fall back to the respective default values.
          -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowGenericHttpRequests</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
            <param-value>Origin, Content-Type</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <!-- CORS Filter mapping -->
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

The ejb module and war module packaged to-gether as an ear and deployed in jboss server successfully. But, the filter is not working properly. Can any one have better idea to enable cors.

Comment: How did you tested it? Your rest works locally?

Comment: Yes, my code works perfectly in my local machine.